# Avoiding overflow error for exp in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing the following function in numpy:

```
def weak_softmax(a):
    b=np.exp(a)
    return b/(1+np.sum(b))
```

The size of array `a` is small but the entries can sometimes be big, maybe as large as `1000`. So I am receiving the following error very often because of the overflow in exponential function:

```
a=np.array([1000,1000])
a=weak_softmax(a)
```

The above code return the vector `a=[nan nan]` and raises the following warning:

```
Warning: overflow encountered in exp
```

Is there any clever way to avoid this issue but still returning the array `b` as intended? This is because all the entries of `b`are less than one only and I feel that it must be possible to avoid this issue using some trick.

Comment: What is the desired result when `a=np.array([1000, 1000])`?  ~`[1/2, 1/2]`?

Comment: Is softmax supposed to have that 1 there?

Comment: @user2357112: It's not exactly softmax. That's why I named it weak softmax. Is there in built function in python for softmax?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide the numerator and denominator by the same factor `exp(c)` for suitably sized  `c`.

The following code uses `np.finfo` to check whether overflow may happen and to calculate `c`.

```
def modified_soft_max(a, SAFETY=2.0):
    mrn = np.finfo(a.dtype).max # largest representable number
    thr = np.log(mrn / a.size) - SAFETY
    amx = a.max()
    if(amx > thr):
        b = np.exp(a - (amx-thr))
        return b / (np.exp(thr-amx) + b.sum())
    else:
        b = np.exp(a)
        return b / (1.0 + b.sum())
```

Comment: I am still seeing the error sometimes, though not often as before. Should I  increase the safety margin or is there some other hack?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon Strange. Could you post an example? Anyway, you could try a larger SAFETY or you could use a fixed threshold (0.0 should do).

Comment: @pikachuchameleon Since you were asking for hacks: Should you find a library function for the standard softmax you can use this like so: `softmax(np.r_[a.ravel(), 0])[:-1].reshape(a.shape)`

Comment: Now the issue is due to underflow rather than the overflow. Can it also be tackled using a similar approach?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon could you be more specific? on my system underflow triggers perhaps the occasional warning but never an error and is typically silently ignored, for example if I do `np.exp(-np.array((0.0, 1000.0)))` I get `array([1., 0.])`

Comment: I'll check it more diligently again and will let you know if the underflow is indeed the source of error.